# looking for pure python package to create images of websites

Tags: python, web, screenshot

I've previously used http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ with http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf/0.2 to create screenshots of websites from the command line. However, I was wondering whether a **pure** python package exists, that can do the same. Currently I always need to download the correct binary of http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ if I switch computers. A pure python package would relieve me from this. Any ideas?

Comment: How would pure Python code absolve you of having to download it?

Comment: pure python code is platform independent. so you download it once and it runs. with **wkhtmltopdf** I need to download the binaries for all platforms that I use. Plus, I like pure python code instead of some pre-build binaries.

Comment: Isn't there a webservice API for browsershots?  That must be available in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require a  browser engine written in pure python. And this means you need a CSS processor und, more important, a complete Javascript engine written in Python. While this is undoubtedly possible, I'm pretty sure nobody has done it.

Comment: [Grail](http://grail.sourceforge.net/) is a web browser written in Python. Its source code may have useful things for doing that.